# Change shade of color of each shape

Tags: java, javafx, colors, pixel-shader

I have the following image and I need to change each shapes color to green but each can have a different shade of green. I am unsure how to do this. I have an idea of how to do it with the whole image by changing pixel color, but not part of the image.

I am very new to javafx so please keep that in mind.

[image]

Comment: I am not clear with the word "different shape of green". And I am also a bit unclear with the question. Can you please explain clearly you actually want to do? is it writing the image ? If possible post the code of what you have tried so far.. so that we can get a quick idea of what you are trying for.

Comment: I imagine OP wants to make each box a different *shade* (type, variant, etc.) of green. He/she knows how to recolor the entire image but not how to limit the colorization to a certain area (à la a flood fill algorithm)

Comment: That is correct Matt, apologies for the typo. I want each rectangle to have a different shade of green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is to generate the image yourself and add each rectangle individually. In this case you can set the color for each rectangle independently:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 430, 230, Color.WHITE);

        List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();

        int width = 100;
        int height = 50;
        int pad = 6;

        // first row
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad, pad, width, height, Color.GREEN));
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad), pad, width, height, Color.GREEN.brighter()));
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad) * 2, pad, width, height, Color.GREEN.darker()));
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad) * 3, pad, width, height, Color.GREEN));

        // second row
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad) * 0.5, pad + (height + pad), width, height, Color.GREEN.brighter()));
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad) * 1.5, pad + (height + pad), width, height, Color.GREEN));
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad) * 2.5, pad + (height + pad), width, height, Color.GREEN.darker()));

        // third row
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad), pad + (height + pad) * 2, width, height, Color.GREEN.darker()));
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad) * 2, pad + (height + pad) * 2, width, height, Color.GREEN));

        // last row
        rectangles.add(createRect(pad + (width + pad) * 1.5, pad + (height + pad) * 3, width, height, Color.GREEN.brighter()));

        root.getChildren().addAll(rectangles);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Rectangle createRect(double x, double y, double width, double height, Color color) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rectangle.setFill(color);
        return rectangle;
    }
}
```

The result would be the following:

[image: image result]

In my example I only used three different green shades, but you can set the color for each rectangle on your own and create gradients or what ever you like. Just replace `Color.GREEN` with `new Color(0.0f, 0.7f, 0.0f, 1f)` and adjust the parameters for your needs.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use the generated Node as image you can use the `Node.snapshot` method to create an image:

```
WritableImage snapshot = root.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
```

If you want to replace the original rectangles with the image you can use the following:

```
root.getChildren().clear();
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(snapshot);
imageView.setX(pad);
imageView.setY(pad);
root.getChildren().add(imageView);
```

To save the image as file you can use:

```
ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null), "PNG", new File("/path/to/image.png"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, But is there a way of doing it to an image.png instead? or would that complicate things?

Comment: Export the root node as image is easy. I added that part to my answer. If you want to use an image as input that would things much more complicated. In that case you you have to use image processing methods.

Comment: I see, thank you very much your help really appreciate it.